# Dynamic JavaScript with ID and custom type

Tags: javascript, jsf, dynamic, jsf-2

I need to get a content like

```
 <script type="text/vnd.graphviz" id="genealogy">
      digraph genealogy {
           ratio="auto";
           rankdir="BT";
           edge [style=solid arrowhead=none arrowtail=normal ];
           node [color=lightblue style=filled shape=box ];
           "118" [label="Max Mustermann"];
           "812" -> "118" [];
           "812" [label="Luise Mustermann"];
      };
 </script>
```

but unfortunately

```
 <h:outputScript id="genealogy">
      digraph genealogy {
           ratio="auto";
           rankdir="BT";
           edge [style=solid arrowhead=none arrowtail=normal ];
           node [color=lightblue style=filled shape=box ];
           "118" [label="Max Mustermann"];
           "812" -> "118" [];
           "812" [label="Luise Mustermann"];
      };                    
 </h:outputScript>
```

just gives me

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      digraph genealogy {
           ratio="auto";
           rankdir="BT";
           edge [style=solid arrowhead=none arrowtail=normal ];
           node [color=lightblue style=filled shape=box ];
           "118" [label="Max Mustermann"];
           "812" -> "118" [];
           "812" [label="Luise Mustermann"];
      };                    
 </script>
```

So my question:
How do i get id="genealogy" (and type="text/vnd.graphviz") into the -Tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source, the `type="text/javascript"` is hardcoded, so you won't be able to do it with the `h:outputScript` tag.

```
@Override
protected void startElement(ResponseWriter writer, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    writer.startElement("script", component);
    writer.writeAttribute("type", "text/javascript", "type");
}
```

From [ScriptRenderer.java](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.1.2/jsf-impl-2.1.2-sources.jar!/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/ScriptRenderer.java?format=ok).

The only way I see is to use plain HTML tags!

Comment: That's what i feared.
I got the problem now solved by integrating the whole dynamically generated script instead of referencing it.